# Can I Update WordPress 2.9.2. to 3.0.4 from admin

Tags: updates

I have wordpress site that built in WordPress 2.9.2. I want to update this version in admin its give option for update old version to new that is  `update to  3.0.4`.Can I do that without data loss.I am  worried because of my database because this site is working.

Please provide me your suggestion.I shall be very thankful to you all

Thanks
Shalu

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upgrade without data loss.

As always, however, it's a good idea to backup your content before you do. WordPress has [some great options available](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Export) that makes exporting data really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question on the same topic...

I have a site that the Theme is VERY custom and I can no longer work with the developer. SHould I be worried about the theme no longer working in 3.0.4. and if so what is the easiest way for me to test my theme before upgrading?

Thanks

eric